# How can I import another class in main class double list?

Tags: java

I'm beginner programmer.
I made a double list in an external class, and I want to print it out in the main class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class A {

    private List<List<Object>> A=new ArrayList<>();

    public List<List<Object>> getA() {
        return A;
    }

    public void setA(List<List<Object>> A) {
        this.A.add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("1+1")));
        this.A.add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("dog")));
    }
}
```

In this class, I made double list and I will put this double list to main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        A a=new A();    
        System.out.println(a.getA());       //this result []
    }
}
```

I want to `print[[1+1],[dog]]` , but it does show `[]`.

What is problem??

I want to print the desired result.

Comment: you don't show your A class, so we can only guess what it does. Since you do nothing with the a instance before printing it, it's likely there 's nothing in it. Just so you know: your test class isn't linked to your Main class in any possible way. Try and conform to naming standards as well

Comment: You don't set any values in your A list in your A class (this is bound to get confusing), so what output did you expect?

Comment: You never call `setA`. Your `private List<List<Object>> A` still has the initial value.

Comment: also, you shouldn't let that setter take a parameter, since you don't use it

Answer (score 0):

You never actually call your setA method from your main class.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    A a=new A();   
    a.setA(a); // <-- populate array list here 
    System.out.println(a.getA());       //this result []
}
```

Comment: it's better to remove the param from the setter

Comment: Agreed, I only included it because the provided method in the A class required it.